# Print ^ in math-mode

Tags: math-mode

How can I print the character `^` in math-mode?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

The character $\text{\^}$ was printed in math-mode.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage/difference in output to what you're doing already?

Comment: you can try $^\wedge$

Comment: `\string^` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\upA}{\string^}
\newcommand{\upB}{{^{\scriptscriptstyle\,\wedge}}}
\newcommand{\upC}{\textnormal{\textasciicircum}}

\begin{document}
$a\upA a\upB a\upC a$
\end{document}
```

Note that the T1 encoding is needed only for the last one (with the normal OT1 encoding, `\upC` will be the same as `\upA`).

[image]

If your aim is to use the symbol to denote exponentiation, don't do it, please.

Comment: Don't worry, my aim is to represent a specific attribute with it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

After some additional fiddling around`\^{}` works well. The actual symbol is pretty small then but thats okay.